# Simple way to make input text transparent

Tags: html, css

I know I can make a input form with default text by specifying the `value` attribute, but how do I make it so the text is transparent visually and also disappears when it is clicked? I want to make my text fields the way [twitter does it](https://twitter.com/).

All the resources I find seem overly complex and I would expect this to be as simple as setting a few attributes, but I just don't know which ones to set. I tried looking at twitters source code in chrome dev tools but I couldn't locate the code which enabled them to use transparent text that disappears when clicked.

Comment: You mean the [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder) attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `placeholder` attribute for HTML5 supported browsers. E.g.:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First name">
```

For old browsers, it is not a trivial thing to implement. Please see these questions:

- [how to use HTML5 placeholder attribute with backward-compatibility in mind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561235/how-to-use-html5-placeholder-attribute-with-backward-compatibility-in-mind)
- [True placeholder text fix for old browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946578/true-placeholder-text-fix-for-old-browsers)
- [What is the most accurate way to emulate the "placeholder" attribute in browsers that don't support it natively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575621/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-emulate-the-placeholder-attribute-in-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

Try the placeholder attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name">
```