# Placeholder has the same value as input value

Tags: html, placeholder

I'm having that old problem when I submit my form: It's sending the placeholder value instead of blank value.

So, after a research, I found this:

```
$("#" + idParentElement + "").find("input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]").each(function() {
      if ( this.value == $(this).attr("placeholder") ) {
          this.value = "";
      }
  });
```

The problem is when the user put the same value as the placeholder. In my case, this is possible.

Which workaround can I use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [True placeholder text fix for old browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946578/true-placeholder-text-fix-for-old-browsers)

Comment: cannot see a duplicate there?

Comment: You could for example add two spaces after your placeholder text. This should at least make it a lot more unlikely for a user to enter that same text.

Comment: Thanks Burki, That is a nice workaround.